# Host web on local machine use xampp

Tags: apache, xampp

I want to access my website hosted on local machine on htdocs in xampp, I want to access it using an IP address, How can I get it where like:

```
https://locahost/
```

and can I get using an IP address?
can you help me the best tutorial link easy step by step to make it on window 10?

Comment: check out my answer

Answer (score 0):

http://localhost:port like http://localhost:8080 i think. You need to specify a port.

Answer (score 0):

You can access your XAMPP website using the following web addresses in the device it is hosted on, usually:

```
http://127.0.0.1:80
```

And

```
http://localhost:80
```

To access your website from your smartphone or another PC, you will need to access it using your local IP address assigned from your router. Run `ipconfig` to see it:

You will need to find the line in the output, like: `IPv4 Address.........: 192.168.0.123`

For port 80 and 443, you do not need to type the number after the address, i.e. `:80` or `:443`. If you are using other ports, you will need to specify them.